# Executing a Powershell command from MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, powershell

I'm trying to automate my workflow. So I'm generating a test list for my system in MATLAB. In the same script, I'm then waiting for a new log file which only gets generated when I run a python script in a certain directory through windows powershell. 
That python script would take the test list generated and produce a new log file. My code looks for the date of modification of that file, if it has changed, it means a new log file has been produced. The code then extracts certain strings of characters and then plot the result.

My question is how can I invoke powershell from MATLAB to invoke that python script execution command in a specific directory?

Regards

Comment: It sounds like powershell is a middleman here, why not invoke Python from Matlab directly?

Comment: The python scripts form the testing tools and they can be accessed only through the command line interface unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to commit to this Powershell-in-the-middle approach, you can call it with `system`

```
system( 'powershell -command "Some Powershell command"' );
```

You can collect outputs from this if there are any.

---

Seems like it would be easier to call the Python script from Matlab though and cut out the call to Powershell, this could also be done with the `system` command (i.e. without also calling Powershell in between). Or you could [invoke Python directly](https://uk.mathworks.com/products/matlab/matlab-and-python.html).

Comment: Thank you for you comment Wolfie. I'm now committed to make Powershell in the middle approach a success ;). So in a nutshell, i need to first get to the directory where the python script is and then i would like to execute the python command. Would this require the usage of two system functions one after the other? Also, i haven't tried this command currently but i believe this would open the powershell terminal in the matlab command line.

Comment: You can probably do it in a single call... I don't know what you mean by "open powershell" but you shouldn't need to see a new window appear